# Adding links to a custom form

Tags: php, html, url

Basically what i wanted to achieve here is adding a "?" to the form url.

My current code that is not working:

```
<form action="'.$config['base_url'].'/whatever/users.php?f=verification">
    <button class="btn btn-success">Verification</button>
</form>
```

i would love for someone to explain what i did wrong so i can learn from my mistake and also possibly solve the issue to retain a good answer along with me learning to see what i did wrong here.

As far as my testing goes everything else seams to be working, what is happening here is that i get redirected to "/whatever/users.php" instead of "/whatever/users.php?f=verification"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo` the base_url into the form action and add the `f` parameter and value to the button element. On submit `f=verification` will be in the POST/GET.

```
<form action="<?=$config['base_url']?>/whatever/users.php">
     <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="f" value="verification" >Verification</button>
</form>
```

Comment: oh :O it was just simple as that? I feel ashamed xD Thanks! (couldn't press the up vote since i have less than 15 rep) ^^ Thanks again!

Comment: No worries. You should still be able to accept the answer.